# Trouble executing a function in the where clause if condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm working on a query along the following lines:

```
SELECT 1
FROM Table1 as t1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t2.firstName = t1.firstName
WHERE
    t2.firstName='John'
    AND t1.age > 14
```

Now I want to run a user defined function that checks certain criteria on an organization id, but *only* if the id is not blank. I tried just including

```
organizationid = ''
AND dbo.validID(organizationid) = 1
```

but because SQL does not use short-circuit evaluation, the function still gets run. This slows things down when it's run on large datasets, which I'm trying to avoid. I've also tried using the `case` statement below:

```
CASE
    WHEN t1.organizationid != '' THEN (AND dbo.validID(organizationid) = 1)
END
```

but SQL didn't seem to like that, I got an incorrect syntax error.

How would I go about running this user defined function, but *only* if certain criteria are met?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft sql server 2008

Comment: Steps: 1) convert your function into an inline Table-Valued function (iTVF), 2) change your query to use the iTVF instead and then 3) just let the SQL optimizer do it's job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must be missing something obvious--why can't you do this?

```
SELECT 1
FROM Table1 as t1
  INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t2.firstName = t1.firstName
WHERE
    t1.organizationid != ''
    AND dbo.validID(organizationid) = 1
    AND t2.firstName='John'
    AND t1.age > 14
```

**UPDATE:**

I would suggest selecting all the records where organizationid != '' and putting these results into a temporary table, then execute the query with the validID call against the values in this temporary table.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid running dbo.validID() unless t1.organizationid != ''. The function is fairly long and it would slow things down for large data sets, so I would like to run it only when necessary to speed up the query.